# Not able to perform CURD operations properly in my Extjs app using Json-Server

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-cmd

I am using [Json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to test CURD operations in my extjs grid. I have put some dummy data on json-server and I am able to read, delete, update and edit that data. 
But When I create data using my extjs app, I am not able to delete or edit that data cause auto generated Id is "nameOfMyModel + autoIncrementNumber".

My Store is:

```
Ext.define('ThemeApp.store.peopleStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        model: 'ThemeApp.model.peopleModel',
        storeId: 'peopleStore',
        pageSize: 500,  
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true
});
```

Model is:

```
Ext.define('ThemeApp.model.peopleModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [ 'id' ,'title','body'],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        //format: 'json',
        limitParam:"",
        filterParam: "",
        startParam:'',
        pageParam:'',

        url:'http://localhost:3000/posts',
        api: {
    read  : 'http://localhost:3000/db',
    create: 'http://localhost:3000/posts',
    update  : 'http://localhost:3000/posts' ,
    destroy : 'http://localhost:3000/posts' 
 }, 
        headers: {'Content-Type': "application/json" },        
        reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty:'posts'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }           
    }
});
```

And I am Adding user like:

```
var UserStore = Ext.getStore('peopleStore');
var user = Ext.create('ThemeApp.model.peopleModel',{title: "Test", body: "Testing" });                      
user.save(); //POST /users
UserStore.load();
```

And For Deletion:

```
var grid =  button.up('gridpanel');
var selection = grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];

if (selection) {

  UserStore.remove(selection);
  UserStore.load();                         
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I am not able to delete/update records which I generate via extjs app? 
The Id of simple post is like
http://localhost:3000/posts/(number like 1 or 2)
and of app generated record is
http://localhost:3000/posts/ThemeApp.model.peopleModel-1

And I can see app generated record in database.json but browser is saying that this url doesn"t exist.

Kindly point out my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason you can't delete them is because they are not created properly. First of all to generate sequential ids use

`identifier: 'sequential'` in your model, than it will generate numeric id's
You can read it in detail here [Model identifier](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-identifier)
After doing this generate new objects and see if you can handle them properly.

Comment: Yes it is generating sequential ids now and my curd functionalities are working fine. Thanks